# some video won't play from sdcard, but same video from http plays good

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have some videos, which plays from http, but won't play from sdcard. Video is absolutely identical. Log cat is:

```
02-04 11:17:21.139: E/PlayerDriver(24273): Creating Non-Tunnel mode playback - uncompressed MIO
02-04 11:17:21.219: E/QCvdec(24273): get_parameter: unknown param 0ff7a347
02-04 11:17:21.219: W/MediaPlayer(15066): info/warning (1, 26)
02-04 11:17:21.229: I/MediaPlayer(15066): Info (1,26)
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273): ======================================================================
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273):                    Open Max Statistics                                
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273): ======================================================================
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273): empty this buffer rate = NaN
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273): empty this buffer total time = 0
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273): empty this buffer count = 0
02-04 11:17:21.229: W/QCvdec(24273): ======================================================================
02-04 11:17:21.229: E/PlayerDriver(24273): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNoResources
02-04 11:17:21.229: E/MediaPlayer(15066): error (1, -15)
02-04 11:17:21.239: E/MediaPlayer(15066): Error (1,-15)
02-04 11:17:21.239: D/VideoView(15066): Error: 1,-15
02-04 11:17:21.239: W/PlayerDriver(24273): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
```

But I think this is not completely log, because in Android source I found:

```
  DEBUG_PRINT_LOW("\n get_parameter returning Height %d , Width %d \n",
              m_height, m_width);
```

I don't find, how to enable low log.

On other devices (like Samsung galaxy S3, android 4.1.3) videos plays from http and sdcard. I tried to convert video into smaller size, so 720x480 is biggest size which plays. Can be problem in video size?

Also I checked, if video don't play from VideoView, it also is not playable with default android media player application.

My phone is Samsung galaxy ace (android 2.3.5)

Maybe someone has same error and founded solution? Or could someone tell next steps for debugging this issue deeper?